# How to time a vim session using 'time'

Tags: bash, vim

I'm trying to log the time I spend working in vim.  I've got a script that works with gvim but when I try to set it up with vim it locks up the terminal session silently or with the message 'Vim: Warning: Output  is not to a terminal'

Here is the script that works with gvim:

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                                                                                                                        

workfile="/home/na/writing/fiction.txt"                                                                                                                                                                          
worklog="/home/na/writing/worktime.log"                                                                                                                                                                          

d=`date --rfc-3339 date`                                                                                                                                                                                         
t=$( { /usr/bin/time -f "%e" /usr/local/bin/gvim -f -S /home/na/.vim/writeroom/writeroom.vim $workfile; } 2>&1 )                                                                                                 
w=`wc -w $workfile`                                                                                                                                                                                              

echo $d $t $w >> $worklog
```

When I close the gvim window I get a logfile containing a date, the number of seconds I spent editing the file, and a word count for the file.

```
2011-08-15 700.15 238869 /home/na/writing/fiction.txt
```

I would like the same using vim in a terminal session.

I understand vim talks to the terminal directly instead of to stdout but I don't care about what vim returns, I want the output from the time command.

These don't work:

```
t=`/usr/bin/time -f "%e" /usr/local/bin/vim -f $workfile`                                                                                                                                                            
t=$( { /usr/bin/time -f "%e" /usr/local/bin/vim -f $workfile; } 2>&1 )                                                                                                                                               
t=$( { /usr/bin/time -f "%e" /usr/local/bin/vim -f $workfile; } )
```

I suspect there's some combination of backticks and paranthesis that will make this work but I haven't stumbled onto it yet.

Comment: This is not a good use case for `time`. Just run `date +%s` before and after, and subtract the outputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backtick or `$()` operators capture vim's output (what you see on the terminal when opening vim is vim's output from its stdout), so you can't do that.

You could try this instead:

```
start=$(date +%s)
/usr/local/bin/vim -f $workfile
end=$(date +%s)
duration=$((end-start))
echo "$duration"
```

Answer (score 1):

Some versions of `time` (eg: GNU's) support a flag to set the output file. eg:

```
/usr/bin/time -o /tmp/foo vim
```

If you're using bash you'll need to use the path for `time` (or a leading `\`) as bash has a reserved word `time` which behaves similar to the `time` command (but operates on an entire pipeline) that does not support the `-o` flag.

Comment: bash has an extremely built-in `time`. It's not even, strictly speaking, a command; it's a reserved word that applies to an entire pipeline rather than just the first process in it.

Comment: @Henning Thanks. Earlier I'd looked in the Shell Builtin Commands section of bash's manpage but couldn't find any mention of a `time` builtin even though the behavior I was seeing looked like a builtin (or alias or function) was at play. I see now, thanks to your comment, that the "builtin" time is described in the Shell Grammar section of bash's manpage.